# Specify simultaneous shifts. Based on date and time for each user

Tags: javascript

I want to specify shifts that are simultaneous for each user.
I want for users who have more than one shift in a day. And the time of their shifts is simultaneous (interruption of several hours or minutes between shifts). To specify
And these shifts should be shown in red. To let users know

I have identified users who have more than one shelf. Now I want if the shift time is the same for each user. Or the shifts interfered with the clock. Show these shifts in red

```js
let tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");

let shifts = [
{"@id":"shift/1","startTime":"2020-05-05 01:27","endTime":"2020-05-05 03:30","ownerId":{"@id":"users/3","id":3}},
{"@id":"shift/3","startTime":"2020-05-05 02:10","endTime":"2020-05-05 04:27","ownerId":{"@id":"users/3","id":3}},
{"@id":"shift/7","startTime":"2020-05-04 13:24","endTime":"2020-05-04 14:24","ownerId":{"@id":"users/2","id":2}},
{"@id":"shift/5","startTime":"2020-05-07 05:50","endTime":"2020-05-07 7:40","ownerId":{"@id":"users/1","id":1}},
{"@id":"shift/4","startTime":"2020-05-07 09:04","endTime":"2020-05-07 10:04","ownerId":{"@id":"users/4","id":4}},
{"@id":"shift/6","startTime":"2020-05-07 06:40","endTime":"2020-05-07 08:10","ownerId":{"@id":"users/1","id":1}},
{"@id":"shift/7","startTime":"2020-05-05 18:40","endTime":"2020-05-05 19:10","ownerId":{"@id":"users/3","id":3}}
]

shifts.forEach((shifts) => {
  let endTime = shifts["endTime"];
  let startTime = shifts["startTime"];
  let ownerId = shifts["ownerId"].id;
  let tr = document.createElement("tr");
  let id = document.createElement("th");
  let dateStart = document.createElement("th");
  let timeStart = document.createElement("th");
  let dateEnd = document.createElement("th");
  let timeEnd = document.createElement("th");

  id.innerHTML = ownerId;
  dateStart.innerHTML = startTime.substring(0, 10);
  timeStart.innerHTML = startTime.substring(11, 16);
  dateEnd.innerHTML = endTime.substring(0, 10);
  timeEnd.innerHTML = endTime.substring(11, 16);

  tr.appendChild(id);
  tr.appendChild(dateStart);
  tr.appendChild(timeStart);
  tr.appendChild(dateEnd);
  tr.appendChild(timeEnd);

  tbody.appendChild(tr);
});

let items = shifts.reduce((arr, e) => {
  arr[e.ownerId["id"]] = ++arr[e.ownerId["id"]] || 0;
  return arr;
}, {});

let reduceId;
reduceId = shifts.filter((e) => items[e.ownerId["id"]]);

console.log(reduceId);
```

```html
<table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">owner id</th>
            <th scope="col">date start</th>
            <th scope="col">time start</th>
            <th scope="col">date end</th>
            <th scope="col">time end</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbody">

        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: what is the issue ?? question is very unclear

Comment: For example, think of it. One user has a shift from 4 to 06:20 on 06-05-2020. And the same user has another shift on the same day from 05:20 to 08:10. Now these two shifts are interfering with time. (Synchronous). Now this user may have several shifts in one day. I want shifts that overlap. Be identified. So that the user understands and does not make mistakes.

Comment: And I want this operation to be done for every user................I hope you noticed

Comment: @xdeepakv...............If you don't understand, tell me to explain more

Comment: idont see any overlapping data.. can u add data

Comment: @xdeepakv... new data added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just create an extra field in shits to map overlapped.

**Sample:**

```js
let tbody = document.getElementById("tbody");
const toDate = (str) => {
  const [dateStr, t] = str.split(" ");
  const [h, m] = t.split(":");
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  date.setHours(h);
  date.setMinutes(m);
  return date.getTime();
};
function loadShits(shifts) {
  let shiftMap = {};
  let overlapIds = new Set();
  shifts.forEach((shift) => {
    if (!shiftMap[shift.ownerId["id"]])
      shiftMap[shift.ownerId["id"]] = [
        [toDate(shift.startTime), toDate(shift.endTime)],
      ];
    else {
      const sTime = toDate(shift.startTime);
      const eTime = toDate(shift.endTime);
      const overlap = shiftMap[shift.ownerId["id"]].some(([osTime, oeTime]) => {
        return (
          (sTime > osTime && sTime < oeTime) ||
          (eTime > osTime && eTime < oeTime)
        );
      });
      shiftMap[shift.ownerId["id"]].push([sTime, eTime]);
      if (overlap) overlapIds.add(shift.ownerId["id"]);
      shift.overlap = overlap
    }
  });
  shifts.forEach((shift) => {
    let endTime = shift["endTime"];
    let startTime = shift["startTime"];
    let ownerId = shift["ownerId"].id;
    let tr = document.createElement("tr");
    let id = document.createElement("th");
    let dateStart = document.createElement("th");
    let timeStart = document.createElement("th");
    let dateEnd = document.createElement("th");
    let timeEnd = document.createElement("th");

    id.innerHTML = ownerId;
    dateStart.innerHTML = startTime.substring(0, 10);
    timeStart.innerHTML = startTime.substring(11, 16);
    dateEnd.innerHTML = endTime.substring(0, 10);
    timeEnd.innerHTML = endTime.substring(11, 16);
    // if (overlapIds.has(shift.ownerId.id)) tr.style.background = "red";
    // comment above and uncomment below, to highlight only second occurance
    if (shift.overlap) tr.style.background = "red";
    tr.appendChild(id);
    tr.appendChild(dateStart);
    tr.appendChild(timeStart);
    tr.appendChild(dateEnd);
    tr.appendChild(timeEnd);

    tbody.appendChild(tr);
  });
}

let shifts = [{"@id":"shift/1","startTime":"2020-05-05 09:27","endTime":"2020-05-05 13:30","ownerId":{"@id":"users/3","id":3}},{"@id":"shift/3","startTime":"2020-05-05 10:10","endTime":"2020-05-05 16:27","ownerId":{"@id":"users/3","id":3}},{"@id":"shift/7","startTime":"2020-05-04 12:24","endTime":"2020-05-04 14:24","ownerId":{"@id":"users/2","id":2}},{"@id":"shift/5","startTime":"2020-05-07 09:50","endTime":"2020-05-07 11:40","ownerId":{"@id":"users/1","id":1}},{"@id":"shift/4","startTime":"2020-05-07 09:04","endTime":"2020-05-07 10:04","ownerId":{"@id":"users/4","id":4}},{"@id":"shift/6","startTime":"2020-05-07 10:40","endTime":"2020-05-07 17:10","ownerId":{"@id":"users/1","id":1}},{"@id":"shift/7","startTime":"2020-05-05 18:40","endTime":"2020-05-05 19:10","ownerId":{"@id":"users/3","id":3}}]

loadShits(shifts);
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">owner id</th>
        <th scope="col">date start</th>
        <th scope="col">time start</th>
        <th scope="col">date end</th>
        <th scope="col">time end</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbody">

    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: 1- Shifts must belong to one user.
Not two or more users.
That is, if the user has more than two shifts on the same day (ie on one date). This operation must be performed.
2. The operation should be performed for each user

Comment: I want this to be done for user shifts.
Each id belongs to one user. I want this to happen for the user's shift, not for all users' shifts.
That is, if a user has more than one shift. Check its shifts.
Do they overlap or not?

Comment: And that shifts should be in one day.
That is, if the two shifts overlap. But be defined in two different days. This should not happen

Comment: But if the shifts overlap. And for one user and be in one day. Make these changes

Comment: you can add one more if-else to match `user's id` not `users id`